# Multi apache2 websites wont work

Tags: apache2, virtual-machine, html

I try to make two websites on the same IP. I have understand on my research that it is possible if i use domain and subdomains.

Right now i made this in my default config file for apache2 on ubuntu:

```
NameVirtualHost prem2.trixia.dk:80
NameVirtualHost srv6.trixia.dk:80
<VirtualHost prem2.trixia.dk:80>
    ServerName prem2.trixia.dk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost srv6.trixia.dk:80>
    ServerName srv6.trixia.dk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host523.trixia.dk

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What i wonna do is, if you go to the website srv6.trixia.dk, it goes to the folder `/var/www/host523.trixia.dk` and if its prem2.trixia.dk, its just the default webpage.

Right now if i go to srv6.trixia.dk it goes to `/var/www/html`. 
What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Apache 2.2 or lower, in 2.4 NameVirtualHost i deprecated.

It is recommended that you put an ip-address to NameVirtualHost with an optional port as argument, like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80
```

On my server I have written it like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

That says to Apache that it can have VirtualHosts on all of the servers ip-adresses. So replace your `NameVirtualHost <servername>:80` with `NameVirtualHost <ip-address>:80`or `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Next I would rewrite your VirtualHost blocks to this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName prem2.trixia.dk
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName srv6.trixia.dk

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/host523.trixia.dk

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

that is, replace the `<VirtuaHost>`part of each of them.

I think the error you did was the two `NameVirtualHost`and that caused Apache to intepret your virtualhosts wrong.

This might be a good page for you to read also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html